# Proof that a piecewise function is uniformly continuous

Tags: limits, continuity, uniform-continuity, piecewise-continuity

Let the function $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ be denoted by:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \dfrac13 \sin(3x) + x^4 \sin\dfrac{1}{x^3}, \quad & x \ne 0 \\ 0, & x = 0 \end{cases}$$

Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\Bbb{R}$

Should I prove this using the definition of uniform continuity? How can this be proved

Comment: The derivative is bounded

Comment: @MatthewLeingang and how can this help me /

Comment: Bounded derivative implies lipschitz which implies uniformly continuous.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Ah okay, however, we didn't learn lipschitz yet

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there exists $M$ such that $|f'(t)| \leq M$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.
Then for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
    f(x) - f(y) = f'(z)(x-y)
$$
for some $z$ between $x$ and $y$.  Therefore,
$$
    |f(x) - f(y)| \leq |f'(z)||x-y| \leq M |x-y|
$$
(so $f$ is [Lipschitz](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LipschitzFunction.html)).  Given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{M}$. $\Box$

---

It remains to show that in this particular problem that $f'(x)$ is bounded, but that's a simple calculus problem.